# All but one input buttons work

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

**Solved** I just used asp:Repeater for the buttons, way more efficient.

I'm creating multiple tables with a foreach cycle and each table contains a button that leads to a separate page. Here's the html code for the button only.

```
<form name='input' action='AuctionDetails.aspx' method='get'>
<input type='submit' value='Bid now' name='{5}'/>
</form>
```

Now, I have a lot of iterations (around 50) and *ALL* of the buttons work, except the *first* one. Even when I filter the results (returns fewer tables), all of the buttons work, except the first one.

Here's the full method.

```
private void FillPageAuctions()
{
    IEnumerable<AuctionClass> query = null;
    var context = new AuctionsEntities();

    string queryString = Request.QueryString.ToString();

    if (Request.QueryString.ToString() != "")
    {
        query = from e in context.Auctions
                where e.Category.Name == queryString
                select e;
    }

    else
    {
        query = from e in context.Auctions select e;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (query.Count() == 0)
    {
        sb.Append("There are no auctions in this category.");
    }

    else
    {
        foreach (AuctionClass auction in query)
        {
            string temp = auction.AuctionName;
            if (auction.AuctionName.Length > 12)
            {
                temp = auction.AuctionName.Remove(12);
                temp = temp + "...";
            } 

            sb.Append(String.Format(@"<table style='border: 1px solid #666666;
                float:left;
                width: 24%;
                margin: 0px 3px 3px 3px;
                text-align: center;'>
                <tr><th style='font-size: 18px'>{0}</th></tr>
                <tr><td><img src='{1}' height='100px' width='100%'/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Price: ${2}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Time Left: </td></tr>
                <tr><td>{3} hours</td></tr>
                <tr><td>{4} minutes</td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                <form name='input' action='AuctionDetails.aspx' method='get'>
                    <input type='submit' value='Bid now' name='{5}'/>
                </form>
                </td></tr></table>", temp, "Untitled.png", 
                auction.CurrPrice, 0, 0, auction.AuctionID));
        }
    }
    AuctionListLabel.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Define not working, does it generate an error?

Comment: Please post in your question only piece of code you are talking. This is not code review page.

Comment: @Bojan ***ASP.Net does not allow multiple form tags in a single page.***

Comment: Just use <a> with get arguments, it will be way cleaner than putting a ton of <from>'s into the page.

Comment: @KarlAnderson it just redirects to the same page.

Comment: @MightyPork I could go with <a> with an image, but I need a button..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In an ASP.NET page, you can not put more than one Form tags.**

The single-form model is a key element for the implementation of the ASP.NET state maintenance feature. Since the page always posts to itself, the runtime finds it easy to retrieve and restore the state saved during the last access. While there are other ways to save and restore the state of a page, using a single-form model is by far the simplest and most effective of all solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the name of the submit button to how ever many values you have: name='/0-50/' you can create a simple loop that can return the values being submitted by using a counter variable.